# using super() in java, hourly employee method

Tags: java, super

I'm having problems with one of my classes. Everything is fine except for the line with the super(hourly) under public HourlyEmployee(HourlyEmployee hourly). I don't know if I'm using super wrong or how to fix it. It just says "actual and formal arguments differ in length. Not sure what that means."
thanks

```
package payrollsystem_1;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HourlyEmployee extends Employee {
    private double hourlyRate;
    private double periodHours;

    public HourlyEmployee(int employeeID, String firstName, String lastName, 
            ArrayList<Paycheck> listOfPaychecks, double hourlyRate, double periodHours ){

        super(employeeID, firstName, lastName, listOfPaychecks);
        this.listOfPaychecks = listOfPaychecks;
        this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
        this.periodHours = periodHours;
    }

    public HourlyEmployee(HourlyEmployee hourly) {
       super(hourly);
        this.hourlyRate = hourly.hourlyRate;
        this.periodHours = hourly.periodHours;
    }

    public double getHourlyRate(){
        return hourlyRate;
    }

    public void setHourlyRate(double hourlyRate) {
        this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
    }

    public double getPeriodHours() {
        return periodHours;
    }

    public void setPeriodHours(double periodHours) {
        this.periodHours = periodHours;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to show the constructors of class `Employee`

Comment: It calls the constructor from the super class. There need to exists a matching.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that do there has any constructors like

```
public Employee(HourlyEmployee hourly) {
  //I know the super class shouldn't know about the subclass.
  //But this is OK if you write like this.
  //It can be compiled without showing any errors.
  /*code*/
}
```

or

```
public Employee(Employee hourly) {
  /*code*/
}
```

in your Employee class.If the super class 'Employee' do not have constructor like those two mentioned above. You will get the message **"actual and formal arguments differ in length"** when you try to compile HourlyEmployee.java.

***This means that your super class 'Employee' do not have a constructor that need to pass a HourlyEmployee or it's super class instance to.***

In fact, You need to show more informations about the compiler error message.I guess you got sth like this.

```
HourlyEmployee.java:xx: error: constructor Employee in class Entity cannot be applied to the given types:
public Employee(int employeeID, String firstName, String lastName, ArrayList<Object> listOfPaychecks)
    required: int,String,String,ArrayList<Paycheck>
    found: HourlyEmployee
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: yeah thats basically what i got. i tried switching things around but it still isn't working

Comment: If you are using Eclipse or any other IDEs, you may should copy the Outline information of Employee.java and HourlyEmployee.java and then paste those information in your question. Nor I can't know the really reason.Now I can only guess what happened to you.